# Desenhar layout avançados Android

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

Estou usando o layout abaixo para abrigar um `BottomNavigationView` e chamar minhas `Fragments`, porém queria colocar a o `LinearLayout` onde chamo as `Fragments` num `ScrollView`.

O problema está ai, quando faço isso numa `Fragment` que tenho dois `EditTexts` e vou digitar os dados, a `BottomNavigationView` sobe junto com o teclado, conforme imagem: https://postimg.cc/image/zd5go6qxn/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/fundo_dashboard"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/conteudo_fragmento"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Qual seria a sua pergunta? De fazer a `BottomNavigationView` não 'subir' junto com o teclado?

Comment: Isso mesmo O_Vagner, ele sobe junto com o teclado, rs.

Answer (score 1):

Dentro do arquivo `AndroidManifest.xml` adicione a tag `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` como um atributo na activity que possui a `BottomNavigationView`.

Exemplo:

```
<manifest>        
    ...
    <application>
        ...
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Existem outros parâmetros além do `adjustPan` mas creio que esse seja o que você está procurando.

Comment: Já tentei isso, ele não sobe o BottomNavigationView e também o ScrollView perde sua função.